# URL match regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bunch of URLs that I need to filter out, based on whether it contains the keyword `'staff'`

```
1. /services
2. /services/EarNoseThroat
3. /services/EarNoseThroat/Audiology
4. /services/EarNoseThroat/Audiology/CochlearImplant
5. /services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic  

6. /services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic/staff
7. /services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic/staff/Jamie-Hudgins
```

I want to create one regex pattern to match all the URLs that have `/services` after the host URL, but not `'staff'` anywhere in the URL. Basically match URLS 1 to 5.

I also need a pattern than only match URL 6 and 7.

It seems like the negative lookahead will do the trick, except I don't know how to put it together. Can someone help me out?

Something like:

```
^\/services\/(?:[^\/]+\/?)*$


OR

^/services\/...any Depth here...\/(?!staff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to match the following:

```
/services
/services/EarNoseThroat
/services/EarNoseThroat/Audiology
/services/EarNoseThroat/Audiology/CochlearImplant
/services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic
```

**Regex:**

```
^\/services\/(?!.*\bstaff\b).*$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQZKUw/6)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `\/services\/` - matches `/services/`
- `(?!.*\bstaff\b)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the word `staff` does not appear anywhere in the string
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of string

Regex to match the following:

```
/services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic/staff
/services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic/staff/Jamie-Hudgins
```

**Regex:**

```
^\/services\/(?=.*\bstaff\b).*$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQZKUw/5/)**

**Explanation:**

The only difference is the positive lookahead:

- `(?=.*\bstaff\b)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the word `staff` appears somewhere in the string before the end of the string

Comment: If staff will always in its own folder, maybe ^(?=.*\/staff[\n\/]).*$ is better so /services/BehavioralHealth/Clinic#staff-later/Jamie-Hudgins and similar don't match.  I don't know if that is a real concern though.

Comment: @Gurman I also need to ensure the string starts with `/services`. One pattern is starts with `/services ` and doesn't have `/staff/` in the string. Another is starts with `/services` and HAS `/staff/` in the string.